# i am preparing one code in Python and i am struck at one point.I want to show my favourate food column wise but it is showing row wise.Need advice

Tags: python

```
Code
=====
Fav_Food=[]
for Food in range(2):
  Fav_Food.append({
  "name":'',
  "Food":[]
  })
  Fav_Food[Food]["name"]=str(input("Enter Your name"))
  for food1 in range(5):
    user1=str(input("Enter your fav item" + str(food1+1)))
    Fav_Food[Food]["Food"].append(user1)
for items in range(len(Fav_Food)):
  print(Fav_Food[items]["name"] +" Your Favourite Food items are")
  print (Fav_Food[items]["Food"] )



Output
=======

Enter Your nameGaurav
Enter your fav item1a
Enter your fav item2b
Enter your fav item3c
Enter your fav item4d
Enter your fav item5e
Enter Your nameGarvit
Enter your fav item1g
Enter your fav item2h
Enter your fav item3j
Enter your fav item4k
Enter your fav item5l
Gaurav Your Favourite Food items are
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Garvit Your Favourite Food items are
['g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l']
```

I need help to show output as:

```
Gaurav your Favourite Food items are 
A ## column wise output
B ## column wise output
C ## column wise output
D ## column wise output
E ## column wise output
F ## column wise output
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to print each item out individually:

```py
for item in Fav_Food:
    print(item["name"] +" Your Favourite Food items are")
    for food in item["Food"]:
        print(food)
```